# Retry policy for Http client

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

How can i improve this code so that the retry applies to all the exceptions which needs retry by default

```
public static readonly AsyncPolicy RetryPolicy = Policy
   .Handle<Exception>()
   .RetryAsync(3);
```

[image]

Comment: [You should not post code (or errors/exceptions, logs, configuration, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7450780)

Comment: Please bear in mind that not all exceptions are retriable. What sort of exceptions do you want to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Exceptions

The `SendAsync` operation [can throw the following exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-8.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_SendAsync_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_):

- `ArgumentNullException` when the request was `null`
- `InvalidOperationException` when the request message was already sent by the HttpClient instance
- `HttpRequestException` when the request failed due to an underlying issue such as network connectivity, DNS failure, server certificate validation or timeout
- `TaskCanceledException` when the request failed due to timeout (*.NET Core and .NET 5 and later only*)
- `OperationCanceledException` when the cancellation token was canceled (*This exception is stored into the returned task*)

Retrying on the first two exceptions will not change anything on the outcome. It will still fail with the exact same exception. These exceptions are indicating problem on the caller side.

The `TaskCanceledException` is [derived from the `OperationCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception?view=net-8.0). So, if you want to retry in both cases then it is enough to handle only the latter one.

```
public static readonly AsyncPolicy RetryPolicy = Policy
   .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
   .Or<OperationCanceledException>()
   .RetryAsync(3);
```

### Status Codes

The above section covered only those cases when the `SendAsync` failed with an exception. But there might be cases where the `SendAsync` did not fail but the sent request were not processed. The `SendAsync` returns an `HttpResponseMessage` object and its `StatusCode` property could indicate retryable problems. Typical retryable status codes:

- 408 Request Timeout
- 429 Too Many Requests
- *(500 Internal Server Error)*
- 502 Bad Gateway
- 503 Service Unavailable
- 504 Gateway Timeout

The internal server error usually treated as retryable status code but it really depends on the downstream system's implementation. You might have called an endpoint which has a bug. Re-issuing the same request most probably will not result in a different status code than 500.

---

If you look at the [remarks of the `AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addtransienthttperrorpolicy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#remarks) then you can see that it will register a retry policy which triggers for one of the following conditions:

- Network failures (as `HttpRequestException`)
- HTTP 5XX status codes (server errors)
- HTTP 408 status code (request timeout)

This could be a good starting point but you might extend the triggers with one of the above mentioned exceptions and/or status codes.

### Idempotent operation

Please bear in mind that not all operations are retryable. Requests which are creating new resources (usually POST requests in REST) might result in unwanted duplicates. If the downstream system is not prepared for de-duplication then you should try to avoid retries.

[Here](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#ret) I have detailed the considerations for retry.